# Is there a way to embed the business central inside the custom spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm, kie-workbench, kie-server, redhat-bpm

Am new to Jbpm, currently am following the tutorial from https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.19.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/, according to the above mentioned tutorials, my custom application runs in localhost:8090, whereas my business central runs in localhost:8080. I can create a business process in 8080 and can deploy it in 8090.
Now my requirement is, I need a single custom application which will start the business central by default. That is, when I start my custom application, it should internally start the business central also.
Kindly provide the solution.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No AFAIK. not at least till now